# Raspberry: GPIOs+Buttons - Same code, different effects

Tags: python, button, raspberry-pi, gpio

I got a problem which I simply can't solve on my own.
Maybe one of you knows more?

I wrote a code which handles my buttons. The first Button on my GPIO2
works fine. However the GPIO21 is buggy. It continues to print the 
message, which is originally preserved for the pressing of the button, directly
without stopping. It doesn't matter, if the if-condition says
elif GPIO.input(21) == True, or elif GPIO.input(21) == GPIO.LOW, or even
elif GPIO.input(21) == GPIO.HIGH.
It seems like the code doesn't care about the condition of the GPIO.
I tried it with different GPIOs but the result stayed the same.

anyone an idea?

```
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
 import time
 import urllib

 GPIO.setwarnings(False)
 GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
 GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
 GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN)
 try:
         while True:
                 if GPIO.input(2) == GPIO.LOW:
                         print("Forward works")   
                         time.sleep(1)
                 elif GPIO.input(21) == True:
                         print("Backward works")
                         time.sleep(1)
 except:
         GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: what is the button, e.g ky040? can you share its link?

Comment: The Button is a pretty basic momentary push button. https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B076SK1HMM/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: Are you sure you want BCM? I don’t see GPIO 21 on RPi pinout. Do you need a pull up/down like the other?

Comment: I got BCM out of a tutorial for the GPIO2-Button and it works just fine. So i thought I'd keep it that way. I looked the GPIO Pins up on this graphic: https://www.bigmessowires.com/2018/05/26/raspberry-pi-gpio-programming-in-c/
Franky, I am not quite sure if I need the pull up/down mechanism. Nevertheless i also tried it with this argument and it still didn't work.